# how to filter an array by key on a table from json with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to filter an array from json by key value when click on checkbox in html and be displayed on a table, but i don't know how to start with javascript file.

I created a function that connects with checkboxes and responses when you press. Inside I have a variable with three options, one for each checkbox.

HTML:

```
<label class="text-light">
  <input type="checkbox" value="D" id="partyfd" onclick="filter()">
  <i class="fas fa-democrat"></i> Democrats 
</label>
```

JS:

```
 function filter(){
  filterparty = checkedBox ["R", "D", "I"];
  filter(hdata.results[0].members.length; checkedBox;)

 }
```

Now I display a table with all json data, but not filtered by value of array.

If leave useful information for this function would be great help, I search in google about it I only get the method Array.prototype.filter () but it's not what I really need.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide an example in an online editor (e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/) or a linkt to the site, so it is easier to help you.

Comment: There is a big mistake here, you call filter in filter function, it will make an infinite recursion but first you will get an exception because you pass ';' in argument

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand, you want to do something like this but we don't know what is in your json:

```js
var yourlist = ['your json as array'];

var filter = function() {
  var filterparty = [];

  // Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox
  if(document.getElementById("partyfd").checked == true) {
    filterparty.push(document.getElementById("partyfd").value);
  }

  // The same for other parties
  // This can be optimized with a loop to get all checkbox values.

  // Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Object
  // replace 'member.party' by the path to the right key in your json
  const result = yourlist.filter(member => filterparty.includes(member.party));

  // return result or do what you want with result
}
```